# Polygon collision (sometimes) not working, possibly float error

Tags: c++, graphics, collision-detection, game-development

I am writing a program in C++ using OpenGL to draw elements. This is a simple 2D game, in which a square is supposed to change its direction once it hits one of the walls, i.e. the bounds of the screen. To set up the bounding box, I have made tiny squares spanning the length of the sides. My coordinate system is from -1 to 1 in all directions.

Sometimes it all works, but eventually the moving square will go outside the window. It seems my program recognizes the collision, but still nothing stops it from moving past the bounds. Here is my check for collision:

```cpp
bool checkCollisionRectRect(Rectangle* p1, Rectangle* p2) {
    float eps = 0.005;
    RectHitbox* rect1 = (RectHitbox*)p1->getHitbox();
    RectHitbox* rect2 = (RectHitbox*)p2->getHitbox();
    if (rect1->x < rect2->x + rect2->w + eps &&
        rect1->x + rect1->w + eps > rect2->x &&
        rect1->y < rect2->y + rect2->h + eps &&
        rect1->h + rect1->y + eps > rect2->y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is how collisions are checked for, for the time being for every single frame:

```
void Game::handleBallWallCollision() {
    bool collisionX = checkCollision(this->ball, this->boundBoxes->at(0)) ||
                    checkCollision(this->ball, this->boundBoxes->at(1));
    bool collisionY = checkCollision(this->ball, this->boundBoxes->at(2)) ||
                    checkCollision(this->ball, this->boundBoxes->at(3));
    if (collisionX) { // Collision X
        ball->flipDirectionX();
    } else if (collisionY) { // Collision Y
        ball->flipDirectionY();
    }
}
```

In order to avoid floating point errors, I have added the eps value. Still I have no idea what is wrong, and why the square sometimes jumps past the bounds. Has anyone encountered this problem before, and possibly solved it by some clever means?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your observations. I suspect the problem is outside of the shown code.

Comment: I recommend to drop the habit of casting like that.

Comment: Hmm, that would be hard, considering the program is like 1000 lines of code in order to produce this error.

Comment: Probably. But the info as given is insufficient. And making an MRE might actually make you find the problem.

Comment: Off-topic `if(condition) return true; else return false;` is bad style, prefer simply `return condition;`...

Comment: @Yunnosch I added some code to show how collision is checked now.

Comment: Just a guess (as there's not enough code for more): are your bounding boxes on the left, right, above, and below, and just touching at their corners?  If your ball has jumped by its own width or more diagonally from just inside in any of the corners, its new position could be alongside two of the bounding boxes without colliding.  That said, why don't you print the coordinates and debug like a real programmer ;-P.

Comment: Nobody except you has encountered this problem before, because this problem is in **your** game. However, people have had collision problems before. However, they are all different. Knowing how someone else fixed a different problem in their game will not help you

Comment: How do you know that the collision was detected?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I reallized this question is not specific enough, and does not meet the requirements given in the guidelines. Thus, I have voted to close it. I will return to StackOverflow with a better formulated question if needed.

Comment: This is pretty clear and the problem is obvious. See answer below. Basically you can't just rely on flipping the direction. You need to make the ball direction away from the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an epsilon. In fact, it is the source of the error.

```
if (collisionX) { // Collision X
    ball->flipDirectionX();
```

When the ball gets to move slow enough, once it enters the area of epsilon, it will just bounce left and right every frame.

But just removing the epsilon will *not* be enough to fix the issue. What you need is:

```
if (collisionXLeftSide) { // Collision X on the left
    ball->goRight();
```

You need to be explicit. If the collision is on the left side, you need to force the ball to go right, and vice versa. That way, due to floating point errors, if you measure two collisions for the same wall, your ball still bounce to the correct side.